# Query to get the list of Addresses that have AddressType one else AddressType two?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the folowing table

```
Id  PersonId    Address   AddressTypeId
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1     1         AI1P1T1      1
2     1         AI2P1T2      2  
3     2         AI3P2T2      2
```

I want to write a query to print the list of Addresses of Persons who have `AddressType =1` or `AddressTypeId=2` and

When person has  `AddressType =1` then select it,
else select person with `AddressType =2`

Expected result:

```
Address
--------------
AI1P1T1           
AI3P2T2
```

Comment: you will need to write a stored procedure with your busines logic. First checking if table has rows for addressTypeID = 1 and if no select with addressTypeID =2

Comment: What is the logic behind selecting `AI3P2T2` instead of `AI2P1T2` ?

Answer (score 2):

Good day,

Please check if this solve your needs:

```
/***************************** DDL+DML */
drop table if exists T;
create table T(Id int,PersonId int, [Address] nvarchar(10), AddressTypeId int)
INSERT T(Id,PersonId, [Address], AddressTypeId)
values
(1,1,'AI1P1T1',1),
(2,1,'AI2P1T2',2),
(3,2,'AI3P2T2',2)
GO

select * from T
GO

/***************************** Solution */
With MyCTE as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by PersonId order by AddressTypeId) as RN
    from T
)
select [Address]
from MyCTE
where 
    AddressTypeId in (1,2) -- if there can be only positive numbers then you can use "< 3"
    and RN = 1
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also using joins:

```
 select t1.PersonId,t1.Address from #T t1 
  inner join (select personid,min(AddressTypeId)atype from #T
  group by PersonId )x 
  on x.atype=t1.AddressTypeId and x.PersonId=t1.PersonId
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a subquery to make `ROW_NUMBER` by *window function*, then use `MAX` in the main query.

```
SELECT 
    PersonId, MAX(Address) Address
FROM 
    (SELECT
         PersonId,
         (CASE 
             WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY PersonId) = 1 
                THEN Address 
          END) Address
     FROM 
         T
     WHERE 
         AddressTypeId IN (1,2)
    ) t1
GROUP BY 
    PersonId
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6bae7/25)

**[Results]**:

```
| PersonId | Address |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | AI1P1T1 |
|        2 | AI3P2T2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select personId, last_value(Address) over(partition by personId order by AddressTypeId) as Address
from table
--use the where statement optionally
--where AddressTypeId in (1,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want distinct PersonId

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar This query returns one row by one personId so I don't get you to comment quite. Please, clarify =)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the top 1 with ties trick:

```
select top 1 * with ties
from yourtable 
order by row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by AddressTypeId)
```

This will also work for versions <2012, and can return every field

Answer (score 0):

You could use an union between the result for  the result for only 1, only 2 and 1 when 1 and 2

```
  select Address 
  from my_table m 
  Inner join ( 
  select  PersonId , count(distinct distinct AddressTypeId)
  from my_table  
  where AddressTypeId in (1, 2)
  group by PersonId 
  having count(distinct AddressTypeId) = 2 
  ) t  on t.personId = m.personId andm.AddressTypeId = 1 

  UNION 
  select Address 
  from my_table m 
  Inner join ( 
  select  PersonId , count(distinct distinct AddressTypeId)
  from my_table  
  where AddressTypeId in ( 2)
  group by PersonId 
  having count(distinct AddressTypeId) = 1
  ) t  on t.personId = m.personId andm.AddressTypeId = 2 

  UNION 
  select Address 
  from my_table m 
  Inner join ( 
  select  PersonId , count(distinct distinct AddressTypeId)
  from my_table  
  where AddressTypeId in ( 1)
  group by PersonId 
  having count(distinct AddressTypeId) = 1
  ) t  on t.personId = m.personId andm.AddressTypeId = 1
```